# After jquery post I can't read form values with coldfusion

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have a jquery post:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#JqPostForm").submit(function(){
                    $.post("messages.cfm", $("#JqPostForm").serialize());
                    return false;
            });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="JqPostForm">
<p><label for="name_post">Name:</label><br />
<input id="name_post" type="text" name="name_post" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

my code in messages.cfm

```
<cfoutput> #form.name_post#</cfoutput>
```

i got 500 Internal Server Error...

```
 Element NAME_POST is undefined in FORM.
```

but, if I go cfdebug section

```
Form Fields:
FIELDNAMES=NAME_POST
NAME_POST=John doe
```

firebug:
Parameters application/x-www-form-urlencoded
name_post john doe
Source
name_post=john+doe

im using jquery 1.4.3 and coldfusion 7

Thanks

Plutarco

Comment: Wrap the code in message.cfm with a cftry/cfcatch and dump the "error" and "form" variables to troubleshoot the issue. Or post that info here.

Comment: Can you try removing the form scope from your cfoutput. Have you tried running messages.cfm manually?

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me - only change I made was sourcing jQuery from google.  Coldfusion 8,0,1,195765 on OSX.

Comment: I found the problem in my application.cfc <CFSET SetEncoding("FORM", "iso-8859-1") />

Answer (score 1):

I delete this line in my application.cfc

```
<CFSET SetEncoding("FORM", "iso-8859-1") />
```

it works fine!

thanks