# using jQuery ajax post to submit serialized data

Tags: post, coldfusion, jquery

I a problem that has been driving me nuts for awhile now.  Here is the set up:

I have a draggable list that is being used for user navigation.  I would like to save how the user orders the list to a database so it is the same the next time they load the page.  I am using (or trying to) use an ajax call to save the order.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
            revert: true,
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                var aResult = $('#sortable').sortable('toArray');    
                postChanges( aResult );        
            }
        });           

});

function postChanges( result ) {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "model/customNav.cfm",
    data: {order: result },             
    timeout: "5000" 

});
}
```

On the cfm page "CustomNav" I have a simple cfdump to dump the form variable out to make sure the data is getting sent correctly:
(I tried to post an image but I am too new, I will try and "draw" the results from the cfdump)

---

|struct              |
|Fieldnames| ORDER[] |
|ORDER[]   | 3,2,1   |

The problem is, how do I access the order data?  I figured because it was dumping the form structure, I would use dot notation to gain access to the order (i.e. form.order).  That does not work.  When I try and dump form.order I get an error saying the variable order is not found inside form.

I suspect it has to do with how I am sending the data to the coldfusion page, however I am not sure what I am doing wrong. So my question is, if I am sending the data correctly to the coldfusion page, how do I access it?  If I am sending the data incorrectly, where did I go wrong?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try just accessing form["order[]"]

Comment: That worked!  That allows me to set do a cfloop over the list passed in.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I saw a very similar (exact?) question, the answer was that there was a

```
<CFSET SetEncoding("FORM", "iso-8859-1") />
```

in the application.cfc/application.cfm that was causing issues:

[After jquery post I can't read form values with coldfusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025492/after-jquery-post-i-cant-read-form-values-with-coldfusion)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but unfortunately that is not the issue.  My application.cfm has nothing more than basic application variables (name, timeout, etc..).

Answer (score 0):

I did this just this morning.

var aResult = $('#sortable').sortable('toArray');

Change the aResult to $('#sortable').sortable('serialize',{key:order});

That will change the aResult from being order[] to being order=3&order=2&order=1

Run that string through ListToArray(), and you'll have a real Cold Fusion array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  However this did not work for me.  If I use: 'serialize',{key:order} I get an error that "order" is not defined.  If I change it to 'serialize',{key:'order'} and change the data that is passed into the server from: { order: result } to result it passes a blank string in.  Am I missing something?